# In 3D viewer with Redline tools, Can the drawn shapes be resized/moved/selected?

Tags: sapui5

I am looking at the example of 3D viewer with redline tools. https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.ui.vk.tutorial.VIT/sample/sap.ui.vk.tutorial.VIT.12 which looks near to what we want to achieve with our use case.

Can we move/reshape these drawn shapes on the canvas and get the new shapes' co-ordinates?